# getting build error while building gem5 with riscV

Tags: ubuntu, build, riscv, gem5

So I was trying to set up gem5 with the RISC-V with the following command:

```
sudo scons build/RISCV/gem5.opt -j 13( I hacce 12 CPU's )
```

This was inside gem5 file I cloned from a youtube video, in fact I was following his instructions, here is the link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMj-GB8BTd4

The error I get is the following:

```
build/RISCV/base/inet.hh:355:45: error: taking address of packed member of 'ip_opt' may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Werror=address-of-packed-member]
  355 |     const uint32_t *addext() const { return &opt_data.addext[0]; }
```

and after that I get the following

```
scons: *** [build/RISCV/python/swig/pyobject.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I tried using build-essentials and I tried to install the dependencies with the following command but did not work

```
apt-get install git build-essential python-dev scons swig m4 zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: thank you for your attention, can you explain why shouldn't I use sudo in sudo scons?

Comment: Ow,, I get it thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my dear friends, I got the solution, but the problem itself was really hard the occur in first place, in order to problem to occur, you shouldn't be cloning the repo from the link I gave in the problem. I think the repo has some unfinished parts, so you should clone the repo from official gem5 cite, and you should be fine I suppose!